# Transforming java objects with similar dataTypes but different field names

Tags: java, object, mapper

I am trying to convert this Java Object

```
public class abc {

private List<Profile> profile;
private List<Address> address;

}
```

to this object

```
public class xyz {

private List<Profile> profiles;
private List<Address> addresses;

}
```

The dataType of the fields is exactly the same and only the field names are changing. Is there a smart way to transform these objects other than writing a transformer and using the getter and setter methods from each class.

The Profile and Address classes are nested objects which have similar differences in the field names.

Comment: you could try the `PropertyUtils` from Apache Commons [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html). Check the `copyProperties` method. Note that if the `Profile` and `Address` objects , containing references, you have to deep copy them as well.

Comment: The Profile and Address objects are again nested objects with similar field name differences. If i were to use the copyProperties method, i would have to go down each level and copy it then. Is my understanding right here ?

Comment: yeap thats the actual problem. The same applies if you were using simply reflection utils , which again might lead you in a infinite loop. So in case its a requirement for your code , apply proper copy constructors for each class. Otherwise you could use fast the `PropertyUtils`